# PEP 622 - can match statement be used as an expression?

Tags: python, python-3.10, isinstance, structural-pattern-matching

[PEP 622](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/) introduced `match` statement as an alternative to `if-elif-else`. However, one thing I can't find in the proposal or in any of the material online is whether the `match` statement can be used as an expression and not just as a statement.

A couple of examples to make it clear:

Example 1:

```
def make_point_2d(pt):
    match pt:
        case (x, y):
            return Point2d(x, y)
        case _:
            raise TypeError("not a point we support")
```

Example 2:

```
match response.status:
    case 200:
        do_something(response.data)
    case 301 | 302:
        retry(response.location)
```

In the first example, the function returns from inside a `case` clause, and in the second example, nothing is returned. But I want to be able to do something like the following hypothetical example:

```
spouse = match name:
    case "John":
        "Jane"
    case "David":
        "Alice"
print(spouse)
```

But it doesn't compile.

Comment: Well, it’s called a `match` *statement*, sooo… Also, its syntax is pretty complex to be used anywhere an expression can be used.

Comment: @deceze `if-else` is also called _statement_ but then we can do `x = 1 if True else 2`

Comment: That’s a completely separate operator, which is also greatly simplified to just two possible alternatives (i.e. no `elif`).

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar that is a *conditional expression* which is distinct from an if statement.

Comment: You can use the good ol' `{ 'John': 'Jane', 'David': 'Alice' }` instead. Of course, this relies on hashing and is not even remotely as good as what `match`/`case` does.

Comment: Another choice is to extract the `match`/`case` part to a dedicated function where `return` can be freely used without preventing later lines of being executed.

Comment: @InSync Yes, of course, but that seems forced to me. Anyway, I think I got the answer to my question, which is "it can't be done."

Comment: Post that as an answer then. As far as I know it is correct.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's no fallthrough on your hypothetical example. Maybe that helps clarify why it's not possible.

Comment: Related: [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](/q/60208/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Python.

In Rust and Haskell, matches are expressions composed of expressions:

```rust
let spouse = match name {
    // expr => expr,
    "John" => "Jane",

    // expr => {stmt; stmt; expr},
    "David" => {let s = "Alice"; println!("Matched David"); s},

    _ => panic!("Unknown name"),
};
```

```hs
do
  spouse <- case name of
    "John" -> return "Jane"
    "David" -> do
      let s = "Alice"
      putStrLn "Matched David"
      return s
```

...so it's not technically impossible that the Python `match` statement couldn't have been designed to work as an expression. Presumably, the reason it was avoided for Python are syntactical reasons:

1. Python does not have syntax for expression statements (e.g. `{stmt; stmt; expr}`).

   ```py
   spouse = match name:
       case "John":
           "Jane"
       case "David":  # stmt; stmt; expr
           s = "Alice"
           print("Matched David")
           s
   ```
2. Indentation to indicate a block being treated as an expression may look unnatural to some people. (See also: [`match` grammar](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#the-match-statement).)

That said, it is possible your proposed syntax could be accepted in the future.

Answer (score 7):

No, the match statement cannot be used as an expresssion.

This is addressed in the [Rejected Ideas section of PEP 622](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#make-it-an-expression):

> #### Make it an expression
>
> In most other languages pattern matching is represented by an expression, not statement. But making it an expression would be inconsistent with other syntactic choices in Python. All decision making logic is expressed almost exclusively in statements, so we decided to not deviate from this.